# Dagger 2: Multiple entries with same key

Tags: java, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

## Short explanation

Simplified UML diagram that describes by `Components` architecture.

[image]

And there is an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Multiple entries with same key: 
gson=com.example.di.AppPresentationComponent and
gson=com.example.di.gamesession.GameSessionComponent
```

`Dagger 2` cannot decide from which `Component` provide an `Gson` instance.

I never ever work with multiple inheritance. What can you recommend to solve my situation?

I can dispose of `GameSessionComponent` and move `gameSessionManager()` to `GameSessionPresentationComponent`. It will work in my case, but it's sounds like a dirty solution.

## There is some code.

AppComponent:

```
@PerApplication
@Component(modules = arrayOf(
        AppModule::class,
        TextsModule::class,
        AudioModule::class,
        FontsModule::class,
        TexturesModule::class,
        QuestModule::class,
        GameSaveModule::class
))
interface AppComponent {
    fun componentsHolder(): ComponentsHolder
    fun gdxContext(): GdxContext
    fun rxHelper(): RxHelper
    fun textsManager(): TextsManager
    fun soundsManager(): AudioManager
    fun fontsManager(): FontsManager
    fun texturesManager(): ThemesManager
    fun questManager(): QuestManager
    fun gameSaveManager(): GameSaveManager
}
```

AppPresentationComponent

```
@PerApplicationPresentation
@Component(
        dependencies = arrayOf(AppComponent::class),
        modules = arrayOf(AppPresentationModule::class)
)
interface AppPresentationComponent : AppComponent {
    fun fonts(): Fonts
    fun audio(): Audio
    fun texts(): Texts
    fun textures(): Textures
    fun router(): KRQRouter
    fun launch(): LaunchScreen
    fun mainMenu(): MenuScreen
    fun settingsDialog(): SettingsDialog
    fun questInfoDialog(): InfoDialog
}
```

GameSessionComponent

```
@PerGameSession()
@Component(
        dependencies = arrayOf(AppComponent::class),
        modules = arrayOf(GameSessionModule::class)
)
interface GameSessionComponent : AppComponent {
    fun storyTeller(): StoryTeller
}
```

GameSessionPresentationComponent

```
@PerGameSessionPresentation
@Component(
        dependencies = arrayOf(AppPresentationComponent::class),
        modules = arrayOf(GameSessionPresentationModule::class, GameSessionModule::class)
)
interface GameSessionPresentationComponent : AppPresentationComponent {
    fun storyTeller(): StoryTeller

    fun story(): StoryScreen
    fun gameoverDialog(): GameoverDialog
    fun inGameMenu(): InGameMenu
    fun donateDialog(): DonateDialog
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for your components and Application. I am assuming the circle with an arrow in your diagram means 'composition'. Are you sure you want components to 'have' other components?

Comment: @DavidRawson yep, done. My components do not 'have' other components. (if I understand you correctly)

Comment: @DavidRawson I don't want to include all details in question before you asked for code. The diagram is a sample, but attached code from real-life app.

Comment: Is the diagram from a tutorial site?

Comment: @DavidRawson nope, I draw it on my own to explain my problem as short as I can :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Dagger user guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html) talks about two types of bindings:

> Published bindings are those that provide functionality that is used
>   by other parts of the application.
>
> Internal bindings are the rest: bindings that are used in the
>   implementation of some published type and that are not meant to be
>   used except as part of it. These bindings are usually for
>   package-private types or are qualified with package- private
>   qualifiers.

You probably need to be thinking of this when you design your modules and components. What you currently have:

```
interface AppPresentationComponent : AppComponent
interface GameSessionComponent : AppComponent
interface GameSessionPresentationComponent : AppPresentationComponent
```

is a hierarchy where every component publishes *all* their bindings to the dependent components. This is quite confusing especially since your hierarchy of interfaces does not follow the hierarchy of components to dependent components. Set up like this, it is easy to get a duplicate binding. Ideally, you should not reach a situation where you have to reason about multiple inheritance for components.

At this stage, I would suggest you refactor your component interfaces so that they don't inherit from each other and you will be able to discover which bindings *need* to be published to dependent components and which can (and should) be internalized.

The same applies for your modules. Like a component, a module can both publish and internalize a binding. Why not bind GSON in another module at the `ApplicationComponent` level and publish it to dependent components? Then you can get rid of the binding for GSON inside `GameSessionModule` which seems to be causing the problem.